# Why wont it remember the user and password for share?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

I have Win8 Server running, and its sharing a folder. I've created a user on it and made it to have access to this folder.

But when I try to access the folder from my Win8 pc with that user it always prompts me to enter username and password because they were wrong. Entering them gives me access... why can't it remember it from time to time when i access it by typing `\\servername` in explorer??

It does not seem to remember between reboots :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the username and password in the Credential Manager inside the Windows 8 control panel (desktop). I had the same issue in Windows 7 and fixed it this way.